# Does adding more functions (methods) affect android app perfomance?

Tags: android, performance

Adding more code in one single function or create different functions for each of my different code. Which will be better for good performance of my app?

Comment: Just follow OOPS basics and [SOLID](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/) programming rule. That must be more than sufficient at this stage. Make sure you use proper Design Patterns (avoiding singletons) too as part of your SOLID programming.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does but ever so slightly, so unless we are talking about a really really great number of methods (>64000) then you should be fine and shouldn't worry about it.

Using a different method for every piece of code that accomplishes one job is the way to go.

See more on 64000 [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)